# adding text automatically to an email loaded in mailto: link

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, mailto

I currently have a mailto: link on my website so the user can email myself, however what I am trying to work out is how I can add compulsory text to the email they send me. To clarify I want a sentence to load inside the email when they click the mailto: link.

Thanks

the html code for the mailto: link is below

```
<div align="center"><a href="mailto:interns@cambridgedesign.company"><img src="mailimage.png" width="75" height="75"/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Body parameter to your mailto url:

```
<div align="center"><a href="mailto:interns@cambridgedesign.company?subject=Your_Subject&body=Your_Body_Text"><img src="mailimage.png" width="75" height="75"/></a></div>
```

This Tool is useful for making Email Link: http://angrytools.com/email/

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

As you can see in addition to the To address, we can easily specify:

1. The Subject
2. The Body
3. CC Address

The latest RFC for the same can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068. The [Wikipedia article for `mailto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) is also detailed.

Make sure you URL encode any text you add to the body and subject.

An online text to URL encoder can be found  [here.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center"><a href="mailto:interns@cambridgedesign.company?body=yourtext"><img src="mailimage.png" width="75" height="75"/></a></div>
```

Added body parameter to the href. `?body=yourtext`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add some additional info to explain what you've done.